# Why angularjs value do not change in app.run method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created some value named information and tried to edit it.
How ever it is not effect in controller.
Then, example in below not working.

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.value('information', []);

    app.run(['information', function (information) {
        information = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }]);

    app.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'information', function ($scope, information) {
        $scope.inf = information;
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p ng-repeat="i in inf">
            {{ i }}
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `information.push(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you inject `information`, it is a **reference** to the `information` object which is stored in Angular cache.

I do not recommend to modify the `value` from the controllers (although you can: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fzk5e68/)).

You'd better use `factory`:

```
app.factory('information', function () {
    var info = [];
    return {
        get: function () {
            return info;
        },
        set: function (newInfo) {
            info = newInfo;
        }
    };
});
```

And inside your controller, use `information.get()` and `information.set()` to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Angular**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.value('information', []);

    app.run(['information', function (information) {
        information.push(1,2,3,4); //use this
    }]);

    app.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'information', function ($scope, information) {
        $scope.inf = information;
    }]);
})();
```

Refer [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MKc8gzsrniLrj78FTwrs?p=preview)